# bounded linear operators and norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}_n:=C([-\tau,0];\mathbb{R})$ be endowed with the supremum norm ${||\cdot||}_{\infty}$, or any equivalent norm - it shouldn't matter. Consider the bounded linear operators $L_i:\mathcal{C}_n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $i=1,\cdots, n$, defined as follows:
$$L_i(\varphi)=\sum_{j=1}^n L_{ij}(\varphi_j)\;,\;L_{ij}(\varphi_j)=\ell_{ij}\int_{-\tau}^{0}\varphi_j(\theta)d\eta_{ij}(\theta)\;,\;\varphi=(\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_n)\;,$$
where $\ell_{ij}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\eta_{ij}$ are normalized functions of bounded variation; $\eta_{ij}\in \text{BV}([-\tau,0];\mathbb{R})$ with $V_{-\tau}^{0}\eta_{ij}=1$. I'm trying to convince myself that $|\ell_{ij}|=||L_{ij}||$. Here is my attempt. From the definition of $L_{ij}$ above, I get $$||L_{ij}||=||\ell_{ij}\int_{-\tau}^{0}\varphi_j(\theta)\eta^{\prime}_{ij}(\theta)d\theta||=|\ell_{ij}|\cdot ||\text{integral goes here}||\leq |\ell_{ij}|\int_{-\tau}^{0}||\varphi_j(\theta)\eta_{ij}^{\prime}(\theta)||d\theta\;.$$
I also know that
$$V_{-\tau}^{0}\eta_{ij}=\int_{-\tau}^{0}|\eta_{ij}^{\prime}(\theta)|d\theta\;.$$
Ideas going forward from here are welcome.

Comment: If you put in $\varphi = 1$ and $\eta = \cos(\pi x/\tau)$ you find that $L_{ij}(\varphi)= 2l_{ij}$.

Comment: For $\varphi_j(\theta)=1$ and $\eta_{ij}(\theta)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{2\tau}\right)$, $i,j=1,\cdots, n$, one obtains the identity $L_{ij}(1)=\ell_{ij}$. Thus, in this case, $\lVert L_{ij}(1)\rVert = \lvert \ell_{ij}\rvert$. However, this is only true for the one particular case. How does one show it's true for any chose of $\varphi$ and the bounded variation functions $\eta_{ij}$?

Comment: The example shows that the norm of $L_{ij}$ can be greater than $2|l_{ij}|$. The result depends on the form of $\eta_{ij}$.